# Simple Transition Effects for Short Video or GIF

Tags: premiere, after-effects, effects, transitions

I'm pretty new to creating GIFs and video effects so please excuse my ignorance. I searched for 2-3 hours for a simple tutorial on this but it is difficult to find.

Would anyone know how I can do this simple task: I have an image divided into 4 sections. I want each section to "fly in" from outside the screen into view, one right after the other until all 4 pieces are there. Sort of like when you make graphics "fly in" in Microsoft Word or Powerpoint.

I have the entire Adobe suite so I can use anything they have. I started creating it in Photoshop as a GIF and I assumed I could probably add the "Fly in" effect to each section of the image but it seems Photoshop doesn't have such capabilities for GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the end of the video, set a keyframe how it should look in the end.
Then go to the beginning and move the images out of view. Add some movement speed curves if you want